# Git/gerrit workflow when working on a CR that is dependent on another un-merged CR

Tags: git, gerrit

Often, I find myself in situation where I have submitted a patch for review, and I want to start working on something on top of that (yet unmerged) patch. What should be a proper workflow for that?

one possibility:
Create a new branch from the branch containing the initial CR, and create work and commit on top of that. Will this create problem when the initial CR is merged and I want to rebase+push the new branch with new work?

Comment: That is exactly the correct workflow.

Comment: You mean create new branch off the branch containing initial CR?

Comment: Right. Your new CR should have the existing CR as a parent.  This is a very, very common pattern with Gerrit. It doesn't matter whether it's a new branch or just a subsequent commit on the same branch.

Comment: Thanks. If possible, please pit this as answer and I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have described the correct workflow.  Your new CR should have your existing CR as it's immediate parent.  It doesn't matter whether your new CR is on a new branch or is simply another commit on the same branch as the existing CR.

The gerrit documentation describes this [in more detail](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit/Advanced_usage#Create_a_dependency).